# Spark DataFrame, how to to aggregate sequence of columns?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, dataframe, apache-spark-sql

I have a dataframe and I could do aggregate with static column names i.e:

```
df.groupBy("_c0", "_c1", "_c2", "_c3", "_c4").agg(
concat_ws(",", collect_list("_c5")),
concat_ws(",", collect_list("_c6")))
```

And it works fine but how to do same if I get sequence of groupby columns and sequence of aggregate columns?

In other words, what if I have

```
val toGroupBy = Seq("_c0", "_c1", "_c2", "_c3", "_c4")
val toAggregate = Seq("_c5", "_c6")
```

and want to perform the above?

Comment: I tried to make the question a bit clearer, please check so I didn't misunderstand it.

Comment: Thanks for editing.

Comment: sounds like you want a DF to be an RDD

Comment: Please provide sample input, It will help to do better.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To perform the same `groupBy` and aggregation using the sequences you can do the following:

```
val aggCols = toAggregate.map(c => expr(s"""concat_ws(",", collect_list($c))"""))
df.groupBy(toGroupBy.head, toGroupBy.tail:_*).agg(aggCols.head, aggCols.tail:_*)
```

The `expr` function takes an expression and evaluates it into a column. Then the varargs variants of `groupBy` and `agg` are applied on the lists of columns.